# Angular: hiding a component with *ngIf doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have just started with `Angular` and have already faced an issue: a button actually toggles the variable I need (*show*) but it doesn't affect the course.component

**course.component** must show `app-csgo-course`, boolean `show` is true because the component is visible, but after it toggles in `navbar.component`, nothing changes.

`<app-csgo-course *ngIf="show"> </app-csgo-course>`

```
import { NavbarComponent } from './../navbar/navbar.component';
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { CourseService } from 'src/app/course.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-course',
  templateUrl: './course.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course.component.css']
})
export class CourseComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  service = new CourseService;
  show = this.service.GetShow();
}
```

In **navbar.component** there's a button which toggles the "show" variable

```
      <button (click)="ToggleShow()" >
        <li class="nav-item active" id="csgo-logo">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="game-logo" src="assets\img\csgo-logo.png" title="Counter Strike: Global Offensive">
            <!-- <a>CS:GO <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> -->
          </a>
        </li>
      </button>
```

```
import { CourseService } from 'src/app/cheat.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  service = new CourseService;
  show = this.service.GetShow();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  public ToggleShow() {

    this.service.show = this.service.ToggleShow();
    console.log(this.service.show);
    return this.service.show;
  }
}
```

The **course.service** file

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CourseService {

  show: boolean = true;

  GetShow() {
    return this.show;
  }

  ToggleShow() {
    return this.show = !this.show
  }

  constructor() { }
  }
}
```

Would appreciate your help!

Comment: `CourseComponent.show` is set once when the component is created and its value doesn't change when you toggle the value inside `CourseService`, that's why it doesn't work as expected. Try to refactor your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new to Angular, let me break it down for you.

1. You need to create a `BehaviorSubject` to capture the event of toggle (this is called reactive programming which is a achieved using `RxJS` in `Angular` ).
2. Do not use `new` for a service, rather **inject** it in constructor.

**course.service**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CourseService {

  private show: boolean = true;
  private toggle$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

  constructor() { }

  toggleEvent() {
    return this.toggle$.asObservable();
  }

  toggleShow() {
    this.show = !this.show
    this.toggle$.next(this.show);
  }
}
```

in **NavbarComponent**

```
import { CourseService } from 'src/app/cheat.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  show = boolean;

  // IMP: make sure to inject the service and not do "new CourseService;"
  constructor(public service: CourseService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.toggleEvent().subscribe(showFlag => {
       this.show  = showFlag;
    })
  }

  public ToggleShow(): void {
    this.service.toggleShow();
  }
}
```

in **courseComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { CourseService } from 'src/app/course.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-course',
  templateUrl: './course.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course.component.css']
})
export class CourseComponent implements OnInit {
 
 show: boolean ;
 // IMP: make sure to inject the service and not do "new CourseService;"
  constructor(public service: CourseService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.toggleEvent().subscribe(showFlag => {
       this.show  = showFlag;
    })
  }
  
}
```

---

**PS:** I would suggest you to read about "how to unsubscribe an observable" and how it causes memory leaks. Once you get some idea, you should implement that in the above provided code as well. That's a best practice. Happy learning. Let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: @FrancisMcClain: Happy learning :) Feel free to upvote the answer as well